# Como encontrar un carácter de una cadena y reemplazarlo por otro carácter en la misma posición en python

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.7

espero me puedan ayudar con mi duda de programación en python, ya actualice el código y lo que necesito es crear la columna "futuro", ósea reemplazar la únicamente palabra subrayada en presente y cambiarla por la de futuro, siempre estará en la misma posición.

Tengo las siguiente tablas:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
y necesito cambiar el texto subrayado.

Estoy utilizando el siguiente código:

```html
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import xlrd
import re

ruta = 'C:/Desktop/Prg/'

archivo_1 = 'tabla_acciones.xlsx'
archivo_2 = 'tabla_verbos.xlsx'

tabla_archivo_1 = ruta + archivo_1
tabla_archivo_2 = ruta + archivo_2

extraccion_1 = pd.read_excel(tabla_archivo_1,keep_default_na = False, na_values = [''],sheet_name = 'tiempos')
extraccion_2 = pd.read_excel(tabla_archivo_2,keep_default_na = False, na_values = [''],sheet_name = 'verbos')

df1 = pd.DataFrame(extraccion_1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(extraccion_2)

df1['verbo_extraccion'] = df1.presente.str.extract('([A-Z]\w+)')

df1['union'] = pd.merge(left = df1,right = df2, how='left', left_on='verbo_extraccion', right_on='verbo_presente')

df1['futuro'] = df1.presente.str.replace(verbo_extraccion,verbo_futuro, 1) ##verbo_futuro está en el DataFrame2 y verbo_extraccion es la columna que cree al extraer la palabra en el DataFrame1
```

1. Como puedo hacer que la función Merge sirva como un BuscarV de excel, ósea que busque en la segunda tabla el primer registro y lo traiga, aún cuando la tabla no tenga el mismo tamaño que la primera.
2. ¿Cómo se estructura la función Replace para que el cambio lo considere con un dataframe ya que tengo 2000 mil registros y no los quiero remplazar uno por uno como si fuera una lista.

Muchas gracias y saludos

Comment: Muestra el código que tienes hasta el momento. Asi será más fácil completar lo que te falta (en lugar de tener que inventar y escribir todo desde cero).

Comment: Que modulo estás usando para escribir y leer el excel? Pandas, openpyxl, etc? Podrías agregarlo a la pregunta y como etiqueta por favor? De ese modo podré iniciar a pensar en una respuesta a tu duda. Otra pregunta. Querés cambiar el texto subrayado en el excel? O la tercera palabra de cada celda en la columna "presente"?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.